# The $r$-th de Rham cohomology group is a real vector space

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

Let $M$ be a differentiable $n$-variety, and let $0 \le r \le n$ be an integer. Prove that the $r$-th  de Rham cohomology group $H^r(M) = Z^r(M) / B^r(M)$ is a real vector space.

What I know:

$Z^r(M) / B^r(M)$ is the quotient space, where for $0 \le r \le n$, $Z^r(M)$ and $B^r(M)$ are vector spaces because $d$ (that is derivative outside) and also that $B^r(M) \subset Z^r(M)$ (so is a vector subset).

I don't know how I can prove that the r-th cohomology group de Rham cohomology group is a real vector space...

Comment: Do you know what is an elements of $Z^r(M) / B^r(M)$ and how you write it down?

Comment: You are basically asking why the quotient of two vector spaces is also a vector space. This has nothing to do with cohomology

Comment: @C.F.G Is the real vector space $H^r(M)=H^r_{dR}:= Z^r(M)/B^r(M)$ and is tipcal element is : $w + B^r(M), w \in Z^r(M)$

Comment: @AlbarioPitagorico: and how $+$ of two elements of it and $r.(w+B^r(M))$ for $r\in \Bbb R$ are defined?

Comment: @C.F.G I don't have this information in my notes, I've tried searching but can't find anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a Linear algebraic fact. sum of two vectors $v+u$ and scalar multiplication $r\cdot u$ (for $r\in\Bbb R$) of quotient of two vector spaces $V/W$ is defined as:

$$(u+W)+(v+W):=(u+v)+W,\qquad r\cdot (u+W)=r\cdot u+W.$$

[Now check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) Commutativity, Associativity of vector addition, Additive identity, Existence of additive inverse,  Associativity of scalar multiplication,  Distributivity of scalar sums, Distributivity of vector sums, Scalar multiplication identity for $W=B^r(M) \subset Z^r(M)=V$ that is very straightforward.

Comment: For example the associativity is:
$(\alpha+W)+((\beta+W))+(\gamma+W))=(\alpha +W)+((\beta+\gamma)+W)=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+W=((\alpha +\beta)+W)+(\gamma+W)=((\alpha+W)+(\beta+W))+(\gamma+W)$  ?

Comment: Yeah. As I said it is very straightforward.